# What is the best way to perform multiple requests on a list of ids with RTK Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to perform a single `GET` for each id in a list of ids.

My api is defined with RTK Query and I'm using React and RTK Query's hooks as well.

But I haven't gotten the slightest clue as to how I could perform a request for each id in a list as if I would with a regular function using an http client, such as axios for example.

Some pseudo-code for what I'm wanting to do:

```js
ids = [1, 2]
allData = [];

for(id in ids) {
 data = await api.fetchBySingleId(id);
 allData.add(data)
}

// logging
[{id: 1, ...}, [id: 2, ...}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple options to consider:

(1) You could create a component that uses your query for a single ID. You'd then map over your list of IDs and render a list of those components. If you specifically need the data in one object this may or may not be useful.

(2) You could create an endpoint in your API slice that accepts a list of IDs and then does the API calls manually using the `queryFn` attribute instead of the normal `query` one.

Example:

```js
export const yourApiSlice = createApi({
  ...,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getListOfthings: builder.query({
      queryFn: (ids) => {
        const promises = ids.map((id) => {
          return someManualFetchFunction(id);
        });
        return Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
          return { data: results }; // final result must have either the property "data" or the property "error"
        });
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

Comment: The second one made more sense for what I wanted to do. Thank you!

Comment: I went into the docs after because the queryFn was showing some errors and they have a similar example for this: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#performing-multiple-requests-with-a-single-query