# Is there a good way to perform a GraphQL query for every item in a list with RTK query?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-toolkit

I'm working on a project for a client that uses RTK query in the frontend React Native application.  The backend has a GraphQL API.  I need to retrieve a list of saved items from the backend, but it's set up so that I must first retrieve a list of item IDs, then query each ID individually to get the information about each item.  I currently have the query hook `useGetSavedQuery` which returns a list of all the saved item IDs.  I want to have a custom hook `useSaved` that can get the data from `useGetSavedQuery` , then execute the individual queries for each ID in such a way that the consumer of `useSaved` is oblivious to the fact that there are multiple queries happening.

I initially tried to use the hooks inside a loop, but that's apparently not allowed.  I'm also considering using a query function, but I don't know if that would allow me to use the `baseQuery` .  I'm exploring options similar to those found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990402/what-is-the-best-way-to-perform-multiple-requests-on-a-list-of-ids-with-rtk-quer), but IDK how it's gonna work with the base query.

Comment: The answer you linked to is exactly what I was going to suggest. What exactly is the issue or concern? Can you [edit] to share a [mcve] for what you have tried already or what the current code is? We can't really help address issues in code we can't see, so it would be helpful to see what you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating another query to retrieve the item details for each id.  I decided to avoid `baseQuery` and just do it manually, and it works pretty well.

```
export const api = createApi({
    reducerPath: '...',
    baseQuery: apiRequest,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        ...
        fetchItemDetails: builder.query<ItemDetails[], QueryPost[]>({
            async queryFn(args) {
                const items: ItemDetails[] = [];
                await Promise.all(
                    args.map(async (arg) => {
                        const { id } = arg;
                        const item = await apiRequest({
                            query: ...,
                            args: {
                                input: {
                                    id,
                                    limit: 1,
                                    nextToken: '',
                                },
                            },
                            file: '...',
                            endpoint: '...',
                            publicQuery: false,
                            noAlerts: true,
                        });

                        items.push(item.data as ItemDetails);
                    }),
                );
                return { data: items };
            },
        }),
    }),
});
```